# Return value of 'print' function?

Tags: python

I'm python beginner.
I am wondering what the return value of the 'print' function is.
I tried type(print(3)) and didn't work.

I tried to find the api document but I could only find the pprint function.

Comment: `print` uses `sys.stdout.write`

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: Explain `didn't work`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`print()` returns `None` in Python3.

```
$ python3
Python 3.3.2+ (default, Feb 28 2014, 00:52:16) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> type(print(3))
3
<class 'NoneType'>
```

In Python2 `print` is a statement, so doesn't return anything...

```
$ python2
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:37:08) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> type(print(3))
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    type(print(3))
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

...unless you use `from __future__ import print_function`

```
$ python2
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:37:08) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> type(print(3))
3
<type 'NoneType'>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't know what a statement is, but I can google that. Thank you again.