# Python double print function, I don't understand how this example works

Tags: python, printing

Why does the code?

```
print(print("Hello"))
```

send back to the user.

```
hello
none
```

I don't get it.

Comment: `print` returns `None`; what's not to get?

Comment: the inner `print` outputs `hello` and returns `None` - which gets printed by the outer `print`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return value of 'print' function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22705397/return-value-of-print-function)

Answer (score 1):

`print` is function which does `return None` and have side effect of printing

```
print("Hello")
```

does print `Hello` and `return None` so external `print` does "see" that its' 1st argument is `None` and print that